# How to get cell with row and column number by referencing to cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have this simple spreadsheet:
[image]

I need to get a number value from a different spreadsheet called WEEKS. Now I am using a function

```
=WEEKS!J11
```

I have different numbers as well

```
=WEEKS!L11
=WEEKS!K11
...
```

Next week I have to update manually the end-number 11 to 12 and every week I have to do the same. I'd prefer to do it easier by referring to get the column number from another cell. For this, I created cell called Week with a current number / week and I want to update it every week and update automatically all the numbers. So now we have:

```
N8 = 11

=WEEKS!J11
=WEEKS!L11
=WEEKS!K11
```

If I change N8 to 12, then automatically:

```
=WEEKS!J12
=WEEKS!L12
=WEEKS!K12
```

How could I do it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on *I need to make it more dynamically if I want to change all the numbers to the current column with the appropriate week I have in N8 on the current spreadsheet.*?

Comment: I updated it with an example as I am not sure how I could describe it. Thank you

Comment: Still not clear enough to write a concrete solution but you probably want to use a combination of OFFSET and WEEKNUM(TODAY())

Comment: The solution in the answer is correct. =INDIRECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDIRECT like this:

```
=Indirect("Weeks!J"&N1)
```